# Ruby on rails. Passing params from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters, link-to

I'm having what I assume must be a simple problem but I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to update an attribute in one model when another is created.

In my view:

```
<%= link_to 'Click here to rate this user', new_user_review_path(:user_id => request.user.id, :gigid => request.gig.id), remote: true %>
```

Which passes params `:gigid` and `:user_id`

Than my controller:

```
def new
    @review = Review.new
    @gig = Gig.find(params[:gigid])
end

  def create
    @review = @user.reviews.new review_params
    @review.reviewed_id = current_user.id
       if @review.save
        @gig.update(reviewed: true)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html {redirect_to session.delete(:return_to), flash[:notice] = "Thankyou for your rating!"}
          format.js 
        end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

But I get `undefined method 'update'for nil:NilCLass:`

I know the params are passing and the 'Gig' can be updated as :

```
def new
    @review = Review.new
    Gig.find(params[:gigid]).update(reviewed: true)
end
```

updates the attribute fine, but when I click 'New review' not when the review is actually created.

Adding :

```
def create
    @review = @user.reviews.new review_params
    @review.reviewed_id = current_user.id
      if @review.save
        Gig.find(params[:gigid]).update(reviewed: true) 

etc etc etc
```

gives me the same `undefined method 'update'for nil:NilCLass:`

I have tried with `find_by_id` instead of `find` which makes no difference.

EDIT:

```
def create
@gig = Gig.find params[:gigid] 
@review = @user.reviews.new review_params
    @review.reviewed_id = current_user.id
       if @review.save
         @gig.update(reviewed: true)
    etc etc etc
```

Doesn't work either. I get no errors, but the gig ID is still 'nil'.

The params are passing to the 'New' action but not the 'Create' action. I feel this should be very easy but I'm just not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: You get that error beacuse Gig.find(params[:gigid]) returns Nil. Make sure params[:gigid] is a valid id that exists in the db so it can find it. Should probable do a check that is not nil before trying to call the update method aswell.

Comment: I'm confused, then. Your 'new' action doesn't render a template or anything? How are you calling 'create'? Your link_to generates a link to your 'new' action.

Comment: I am doing it through ajax, but without javascript I get redirected to the 'new' review page which renders a form partial. I then fill out and save/create the review. I want the attribute to update on save/create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I get undefined method 'update'for nil:NilCLass:

The error is that you have not defined `@gig` in your `create` action.

Since Rails is built on HTTP, and [HTTP is stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol#Examples), you have to set the "instance" variables with each new request:

```
def new
  @review = Review.new
  @gig    = Gig.find params[:gigid]
end

def create
 @gig    = Gig.find params[:gigid]
 @review = @user.reviews.new review_params
```

---

A *much* better pattern for you would be to use the `after_create` callback in your `Review` model:

```
#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :gig #-> I presume
   after_create :set_gig

   private

   def set_gig
      self.gig.update(reviewed: true)
   end
end
```

--

If you wanted to make the `Gig` update within your current setup, you'll be best sending the `gig_id` param through the request (not the link):

```
#app/views/reviews/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@user, @review] do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :gig_id, @gig.id %> #-> params[:reviews][:gig_id]
   ...
<% end %>
```

This will make `params[:review][:gig_id]` available in the `create` action, with which you'll be able to use in your code.

Comment: As I need other conditions I used the last method. With hidden field and params[:review][:gig_id] it's working correctly. Don't know why I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you never assigned a value to @gig in your create method.  I can't see your form, but you need something like this in your create method:

```
@gig = Gig.find params[:gigid]
```

Assuming that you're passing the parameter :gigid to #create

In the second example you showed, I'm not sure what's going on, but you should be getting a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception on the find().

Comment: I have tried @gig = Gig.find params[:gigid]  then @gig.update(reviewed: true) which doesn't work either, the ID = NIL. It only works in the 'New' action. I am using link_to, not a form. My link is the first piece of code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for update operation.

```
gig_record = Gig.find_by_id(params[:gigid])
gig_record.update_attribute(reviewed: true) unless gig_record.blank?
```

Comment: This also gives me undefined method 'update_attribute' for nil:NilClass.